# Trying to install win32com on PyCharm 2018.1.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, win32com

I am trying to run this small program that I found online. I was able to download the wmi module (which took a while to figure out), but now it's telling me that win32com is a non-existent module. I am using Python 3.5.2 on PyCharm 2018.1.4 on Windows 10.

Here's the code:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

for process in c.Win32_Process():
    print(process.ProcessId, process.Name)
```

Here's the error:

> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/SoftwareScanner/SoftwareScanner/test.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/SoftwareScanner/SoftwareScanner/test.py", line 1, in 
>       import wmi
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in 
>       from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
>   ImportError: No module named 'win32com'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I tried using `pip install pipywin32` after downloading `pywin32_ctypes-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl`, but it gave me this error:

> File "", line 1
>       pip install pipywin32
>                 ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please help me out.

Comment: Use command prompt not the Python interpreter to install packages

Comment: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Right, so add it to path (or navigate directly to the location where pip is) and try the command again..

Comment: I moved the pywin32_ctypes-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl file to C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32. Still giving me the same syntax error on the console. It was in C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/SoftwareScanner before.

Comment: Right.  Try `python -m pip install` (or add it to path which is even easier)

Comment: I used the command in the Python console, followed by pywin32. It said there was a syntax error at the end of pip (the arrow was pointing to the second p)

Comment: Could I see the error message?

Comment: python -m pip install pywin32
  File "<input>", line 1
    python -m pip install pywin32
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'll just put the error to avoid confusion:

Comment: File "<input>", line 1 python -m pip install pywin32 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Don't call the command using the Python interpreter; `pip` is an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled all previously installed python versions.
Download latest python (python-3.10.6-amd64.exe) and Install it freshly (not pycharm, because in pycharm also you need to install pkg separately).
Then installed win32com by:

```
pip install pywin32
or
pip install pypiwin32
or
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

And compile the program. It should work.